# Laravel | Middleware binding not accessible in controller

Tags: php, laravel, middleware

I have a middleware which just grabs the sub domain and binds it to the `Store` model.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use App\Models\Store;

class SubDomain
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string|null  $guard
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        $sub_domain = array_first(explode('.', $request->getHost()));

        app()->bind(Store::class, function () use ($sub_domain) {
           return Store::query()->where('sub_domain', $sub_domain)->firstOrFail();
        });

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

However, when I am inside of a controller I am trying to extend it so I can always do `$this->store->id` or something alike however, the Store isn't getting found.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Store;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;

class Controller extends BaseController
{
    use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;

    /**
     * @var Store
     */
    protected $store;

    /**
     * Controller constructor.
     *
     * @param Store $store
     */
    public function __construct(Store $store)
    {
        $this->store = $store;
    }
}
```

The store is always just a basic model with no data.

This is my route:

```php
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'sub_domain'], 'prefix' => 'admin'], function () {
   Route::get('/dashboard', 'Admin\DashboardController@index');
});
```

And I have registered the sub_domain middleware inside of the `Kernel`.

Answer (score 0):

The service container and model do not work how you are expecting in your code. So try with the following code snippet inside the controller's method. You may get what you are looking for.

```
$store = app(Store::class);

dd($store);
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to bind an instance of a model so use `app()->instance(Store::class, $store)`

ref: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/container#binding